# R language: why i can get the below outcome like this by Sapply function?

Tags: r, sapply

```
 x<- split(mtcars,mtcars$cyl)
 sapply(x,'[',"mpg")
```

"From the above code, could someone explain to me why I can get the following outcome and why putting `'['` in the `sapply` can get the following outcome?"

```
$`4.mpg`
 [1] 22.8 24.4 22.8 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 27.3 26.0 30.4 21.4

$`6.mpg`
[1] 21.0 21.0 21.4 18.1 19.2 17.8 19.7

$`8.mpg`
 [1] 18.7 14.3 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 15.8 15.0
```

Comment: Just see `help('[')`.

Comment: In R, everything is a function. `[` is also a function. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/360/getting-started-with-r-language/18649/variables#t=201701071334116013822).

Comment: Here's an excellent explanation of why and how this works: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#all-calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the args for `sapply()`, you will see that the first three unnamed arguments given to it will be treated the input data (`X`), the function to be applied (`FUN`) and additional arguments to pass to that function (`...`)

```
> args('sapply')
function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 

> help('sapply')
...
     X: a vector (atomic or list) or an ‘expression’ object.  Other
          objects (including classed objects) will be coerced by
          ‘base::as.list’.

     FUN: the function to be applied to each element of ‘X’: see
          ‘Details’.  In the case of functions like ‘+’, ‘%*%’, the
          function name must be backquoted or quoted.

     ...: optional arguments to ‘FUN’.
```

So when you call `sapply(x,'[',"mpg")` on the list resulting from the split on `mpg`, you are effectively calling the indexing operator `[` on each element in the list, and passing the string `mpg` to it, e.g.:

```
x$`4`['mpg']
                mpg
Datsun 710     22.8
Merc 240D      24.4
Merc 230       22.8
Fiat 128       32.4
Honda Civic    30.4
Toyota Corolla 33.9
Toyota Corona  21.5
Fiat X1-9      27.3
Porsche 914-2  26.0
Lotus Europa   30.4
Volvo 142E     21.4
```

Finally, in the process of assembling the results back into a list, the names are lost, so you end up with:

```
$`4.mpg`
 [1] 22.8 24.4 22.8 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 27.3 26.0 30.4 21.4
```